# Expected area of an internal triangle determined by a random point in a triangle

Tags: probability, area, geometric-probability

A point **M** is chosen at random (uniformly) inside an equilateral triangle **ABC** of area 1. How to find the expected area of the triangle **ABM**?

Comment: Hint: $$ {\bf E}[ \verb/Area/(\triangle ABM) ]
= {\bf E}[ \verb/Area/(\triangle BCM) ]
= {\bf E}[ \verb/Area/(\triangle CAM) ]$$

Comment: @achille hui 
But why is it so?

Comment: It is "obvious" once you remember $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral! Actually, we can drop the "equilateral" requirement. Under linear transform of the form 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} \mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}x' \\ y'\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}e \\ f\end{bmatrix}
$$
the ratio of areas of any two geometric shapes are preserved. Since one can always find a linear transform which map a general triangle to an equilateral one, the statement is true for any triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to prove that the expected area is equal to the volume of the right pyramid with base $ABC$ and height 1. The answer is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Hint: show that the height above any point $M\in\Delta ABC$ in the right pyramid is the area of $ABM$.

Comment: Can't get this geometric reasoning. Can you help me with building the probability space?

Comment: Ok, i got this finally. Joint density is 1 everywhere, so we can calculate the expected value as an iterated integral over the triangle with the linear function that changes from 0 at A to 1 at C. It is a right pyramid, and the integral is it's volume.

Comment: Exactly what I had in my mind.

Comment: A proof that the area is 1/3 can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525061